# Controlling instantiated GameObject using kinect

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I tried some scripts to control an object form the hierarchy and it worked great,

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using Windows.Kinect;

public class DetectJoint : MonoBehaviour {

public GameObject BodySrcManager;
public JointType TrackedJoint;
private BodySourceManager bodyManager;
private Body[] bodies = null;
public float multiplier = 10f;

void Start()
{
    if (BodySrcManager == null)
    {
        Debug.Log("Assign Game Objects with body source manager");
    }
    else
    {
        bodyManager = BodySrcManager.GetComponent<BodySourceManager>();
    }
}

void Update()
{
    if (bodyManager == null)
    {
        Debug.Log("bodyManager is Null");
        return;
    }


    bodies = bodyManager.GetData();


    if (bodies == null)
    {
        Debug.Log("bodies is Null");
        return;
    }
    foreach (var body in bodies)
    {
        if (body == null)
        {
            continue;
        }
        if (body.IsTracked)
        {
            var pos = body.Joints[TrackedJoint].Position;
            gameObject.transform.position = new Vector3(pos.X * multiplier, pos.Y * multiplier);
        }
    }
}
```

}

and a script named BodySourceManager which is

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using Windows.Kinect;

public class BodySourceManager : MonoBehaviour 
{
    private KinectSensor _Sensor;
    private BodyFrameReader _Reader;
    private Body[] _Data = null;

    public Body[] GetData()
    {
        return _Data;
    }


    void Start () 
    {
        _Sensor = KinectSensor.GetDefault();

        if (_Sensor != null)
        {
            _Reader = _Sensor.BodyFrameSource.OpenReader();

            if (!_Sensor.IsOpen)
            {
                _Sensor.Open();
            }
        }   
    }

    void Update () 
    {
        if (_Reader != null)
        {
            var frame = _Reader.AcquireLatestFrame();
            if (frame != null)
            {
                if (_Data == null)
                {
                    _Data = new Body[_Sensor.BodyFrameSource.BodyCount];
                }

                frame.GetAndRefreshBodyData(_Data);

                frame.Dispose();
                frame = null;
            }
        }    
    }

    void OnApplicationQuit()
    {
        if (_Reader != null)
        {
            _Reader.Dispose();
            _Reader = null;
        }

        if (_Sensor != null)
        {
            if (_Sensor.IsOpen)
            {
                _Sensor.Close();
            }

            _Sensor = null;
        }
    }
}
```

the problem is i couldn't control an instantiated one from Prefabs

any ideas how to do it ?

Comment: Where exactly is the instantiated object? I can't seem to find it. I'm expecting GameObject newThing = Instantiate(ThingPrefab); but I am not seeing it...

Comment: it's not in this code, did you work with unity before?

Comment: "i couldn't control an instantiated one from Prefabs" It'd be useful to see where you tried to control the instantiated one for us to answer your question. I'm going on a hunch here but are you perhaps trying to modify the prefab itself and not the newly instantiated object?

Comment: see the example in the video [link](https://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/2p-start/Gesture-Control-with-Kinect-and-Unity-made-easy)